# Mongodb automatic Replica Set creation with JS driver

Tags: replication, mongodb, automation, node.js

The MongoDB docs state that one can use the mongo client console to initialize replica sets by running `rs.initiate([config])`. However, I don't want to have to manually use the command line for this. There is a driver method called `Admin.command` in the docs but I don't know how that would work here. How do I automate configuring replica sets using the MongoDB JS driver?

I have a js script that initializes my database installation by creating the data folder and automatically setting up users for access control. I want it to also configure the replica set so the database is completely ready to use after running it. I'm using MongoDB 4.2.1 and driver version 3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `rs.initiate` can only be used in the MongoDB shell, for drivers you have to use [Database Commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/nav-replication/).

For example:

```
myMongoClientVariable.db("myDB").admin().command( { 
    replSetInitiate : {
        _id : "myReplicaSet",
        members : [
            {_id : 0, host : "host0"},
            {_id : 1, host : "host1"},
            {_id : 2, host : "host2"}
        ]
    }
} );
```

Comment: When I try to run a command while connecting to a mongodb instance with the `--replySet` argument I get the error `MongoError: topology was destroyed`

Comment: Are your driver connection configured for Replica Sets? See http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/reference/connecting/connection-settings/

Comment: When you change from Standalone to ReplicaSet, the topology changes. See http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/reference/management/sdam-monitoring/ and http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/reference/unified-topology/

Comment: so how do I prevent it from throwing this error when I try to send a command after changing the topology? Do I need to instantiate a new instance of MongoClient with `connect`?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a new connection.